# PyTorch: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm new to pytorch and I am creating a one hot encoding function for multi-layer perceptron but I'm having some issues. Here is the code:

```
def one_hot_encoding(label):
    for idx, val in enumerate(label):
        one_hot_outputs = [0]*len(label)
        idx_n = idx[val]
        one_hot_outputs[idx_n] = 1
return one_hot_outputs
```

I'm having a type error saying:

```
in one_hot_encoding(label)
  2     for idx, val in enumerate(label):
  3         one_hot_outputs = [0]*len(label)
> 4         idx_n = idx[val]
  5         one_hot_outputs[idx_n] = 1
  6     return one_hot_outputs
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Any help?

Comment: instead of using `idx_n = idx[val]` you should use `idx_n = label[idx]`. `idx` is only an integer. You cannot apply an index to it. What you want to access is an element with index `val` of `label`. How ever, I don't understand what you are trying here. The value of `label[idx]` of stored in `val` anyway

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is, I'm trying to change the value I want to 1 and all other values to 0. What do you mean the value of `label[idx]` is stored in `val`??

Comment: I suggest you check the documentation for the python enumerate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct answer, but an alternative. PyTorch already has functionality for this: [`torch.nn.functional.one_hot`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.functional.one_hot.html). So, if you have a label tensor `label` and `n` classes, just call:

```
torch.nn.functional.one_hot(label, num_classes=n)
```